# activemq broker redeliveryPlugin configuration not working for topic

Tags: activemq-classic

I have the following configuration in by conf/activemq.xml file

```
    <plugins>
        <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                    <defaultEntry>
                        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="20" useExponentialBackOff="true" initialRedeliveryDelay="60000" redeliveryDelay="60000" maximumRedeliveryDelay="600000"/>
                    </defaultEntry>
                </redeliveryPolicyMap>
            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
        </redeliveryPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

I am using activemq-5.11 with Spring/JMS/Camel/JTA (Atomikos).

Because, I am using JTA/XA transactions, the redelivery policy at the activeMQ connection factory is not working for topics.
So I am trying to set the redelivery Policy on the server.

However, it seems to be continuously resending the topic message.

PS. I have only one subscriber (durable).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.
In my case, the issue was that I was using the redelivery policy at the client side also. And somehow, that was messing it up.

Since I am using JTA, I wanted no retying at the client side and wanted the message to be retired from the ActiveMQ broker server. And Once I removed all error handling and redelivery policy from the Camel configuration, it worked like as it should.

Hope this helps someone in the future.